# What are module-info mode switch statements?

Tags: tcl, environment-modules, modulefile

The package [Environment Modules](http://modules.sourceforge.net/) defines the `module-info mode` command.  [The man page for modulefile](http://modules.sourceforge.net/man/modulefile.html) lists the possible modes as:

```
load, remove, display, help, whatis, switch, switch1, switch2, or switch3.
```

What are the multiple switch statements?

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't find this documented anywhere, so I figured it out and want to share with you.  Here's my explanation.  Consider the following:

```
module load a
module swap a b
```

Here's what's executed under the hood by environment modules for each statement:

1. `module load a`

   1. `[ module-info mode ] == "load" for modulefile a`
2. `module swap a b`

   1. `[module-info mode] == "switch1"` for modulefile a. This should unset prereqs and is similar to remove
   2. `[module-info mode] == "switch2"` for modulefile b. This should add any dependencies. Simliar to "load"
   3. `[module-info mode] == "switch3"` for modulefile a. Not sure why you'd need this.

Comment: I confess to never having understood the `module` stuff at all. (I don't use it on any of my systems.) Alas, this means I've got no idea whether your answer is right. However, it does sound like a multi-stage swap where there's some sort of transfer of responsibility. Can the state changes fail? If `switch2` can fail, that's a reason to have `switch3` (and that pattern in general)…